# Build fail with the COMPILETODALVIK error in TFS but it build properly in my local machine

Tags: xamarin, tfs, xamarin.forms, azure-pipelines, hockeyapp

I have implemented the continuous integration of xamarin.form project with TFS. **I am using "Hosted VS2017" as agent queue.** Since few days I am facing one issue, my code builds successfully on my machine but not in TFS. Nuget restores successfully but "Build Xamarin.Android Project xyz/xyz.Android/xyz.Android.csproj" fails and it shows me below error

> **COMPILETODALVIK (0, 0) COMPILETODALVIK(0,0): Error :**
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2028,3):
>   Error XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the
>   value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while
>   executing 'java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\lib\dx.jar" --no-strict
>   --dex --output=obj\Release\android\bin obj\Release\android\bin\classes "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.0\mono.android.jar"
>   obj\Release__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar
>   obj\Release__library_projects__\HockeySDK.AndroidBindings\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Release__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Relea...
>
> **Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.**

**Error XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -jar**

**I increase the heap size to 1G, 2G but none of the solution work for me.**

**Its properly working on my machine but not working in TFS**

Usually, When this kind of error comes into our visual studio it may be solved by rebuilding the project. **How to rebuild the project into TFS?**

I have tried different possible solutions but can't able to resolve the issue

Comment: What about selecting the default **Hosted** agent?

Comment: Are you using "Xamarin.Android" task to build the project? What's the result if you change "MSBuild Architecture" to "MSBuild x64" in the task settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Enable clean source option ： Set **Clean** to **True** in the first
  **Get Srouces** step.
- Also enable the **Clean** option in build step.
- Select the latest JDK version (JDK 8), and select **X64** as the JDK
  Architecture.
- Reference : [Xamarin Android Out of Memory Build Failure](http://www.andrewhoefling.com/xamarin/2017/03/16/Xamarin-Android-Out-Of-Memory-Build-Failure..html) to set
  **Allow Large Heap**

Then try it again.

If that still not work, you can try to [deploy a private agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows), then install/set SDK/components on the private anent machine same as your Develop machine which worked locally. Then select the private agent to build.

Comment: Allow large heap is working. No need to do rest of the things.

Answer (score 0):

Use JDK8 and x64 in VSTS build. Only this combination works as of now. JDK9 x64 or JDK x86 doesn't work....